# TinyMCE - How can I turn off Visual Aids for printing?

Tags: javascript, plugins, printing, tinymce

I recently added TinyMCE 4.0b2 to a web application I've been developing.

I needed to have visual aids turned on for editing, however turned off when printing and spent a fair amount of time looking for a solution through their forums, StackOverflow and google to no avail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I decided to investigate the issue myself!

To get this to work I had to manually 'adjust' the print command of the print plugin.

The following fix applies to TinyMCE v.4.0b2, the version available at time of writing; it may or may not work with previous and future versions of TinyMCE.

The print plugin file can be found in the js/tinymce/plugin/print/ directory.

Open the plugin.min.js file in your favourite editor and you'll see something like this:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add("print",function(e){e.addCommand("mcePrint",function(){e.getWin().print();}),e.addButton("print",{title:"Print",cmd:"mcePrint"}),e.addMenuItem("print",{text:"Print",cmd:"mcePrint",icon:"print",shortcut:"Ctrl+P",context:"file"})});
```

After poking around the tinymce source code I found the **hasVisual** editor property and **mceToggleVisualAid** command. I then added these two to the printing plugin as

```
if(e.hasVisual){e.execCommand("mceToggleVisualAid");}
```

just prior to the code calling

`e.getWin().print();`

The finished product looks like so:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add("print",function(e){e.addCommand("mcePrint",function(){if(e.hasVisual){e.execCommand("mceToggleVisualAid");} e.getWin().print();}),e.addButton("print",{title:"Print",cmd:"mcePrint"}),e.addMenuItem("print",{text:"Print",cmd:"mcePrint",icon:"print",shortcut:"Ctrl+P",context:"file"})});
```

I hope this helps someone struggling with this issue in future.